# TinkerPop problem with multiple filters using and/or

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I was filtering multiple properties and fetching a node, so if had multiple `filter` joined with `and` and `or`. 2 work fine but from the 3rd it seems to crash.

Below is a simplified demonstration of the error.

**With `filter`**

```
gremlin> g.V().filter(has("name", "marko"))
==>v[1]

gremlin> g.V().filter(has("name", "marko")).and().filter(has("name", "marko"))
==>v[1]

gremlin> g.V().filter(has("name", "marko")).and().filter(has("name", "marko")).and().filter(has("name", "marko"))
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

**Without `filter`**

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name", "marko")
==>v[1]

gremlin> g.V().has("name", "marko").and().has("name", "marko")
==>v[1]

gremlin> g.V().has("name", "marko").and().has("name", "marko").and().has("name", "marko")
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

---

**`dummy-name` is something that does not exist**. still crashes with a different error

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("dummy-name").filter(has("name", "a").or().has("name", "b").or().has("name", "c"))
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
    Display stack trace? [yN]y
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

when connecting to NEO4J and using `filter` it throws me

```
test_gremlin.py", line 49, in execut_final_query
    results = future_results.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/admin-12/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/resultset.py", line 81, in cb
    f.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/admin-12/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 77, in _receive
    self._protocol.data_received(data, self._results)
  File "/home/admin-12/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 106, in data_received
    "{0}: {1}".format(status_code, data["status"]["message"]))
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 597: None
```

**Am I writing the wrong query? or is this a bug?**

---

Version: Gremlin 3.3.1

Comment: this seems to work `g.V().filter(__.or(has("name", "marko"), has("name", "marko"), has("name", "marko")))` but then I cannot do `a` and `b` or `c` and `d`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why multiple `and()` conditions don't work offhand, though I suppose they should, so I created an issue in JIRA for that: [TINKERPOP-2029](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2029)

This does work however:

```
gremlin> g.V().and(filter(has("name", "marko")), filter(has("name", "marko")), filter(has("name", "marko")))
==>v[1]
```

or more simply:

```
gremlin> g.V().and(has("name", "marko"), has("name", "marko"), has("name", "marko"))
==>v[1]
```

In your comment on the question you wrote that you want to really do `a` and `b` or `c` and `d` - that seems possible with this approach:

```
gremlin> g.V().or(and(has('name','marko'),has('age',29)),and(has('name','josh'),has('age',32)))
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```

or in this case more simply as:

```
gremlin> g.V().or(has('name','marko').has('age',29),has('name','josh').has('age',32))
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```

Comment: yes its working. Robert, suggested a similar in gremlin group.